# Use Cauchy Series for power three

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I want to solve a nonlinear differential equation, using the power series. If I have a term such as $y^3(x)$ then I should use  $^3(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i $ to simplify a term

$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k $

The Cauchy Product helps me to simplify

$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j = \sum_{i=0}^\infty  \sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}  a_j x^i $

But I am not sure if the form

$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k = \sum_{i=0}^\infty  \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{k=0}^j a_{i-j-k}  a_j a_k x^i $

is true for power 3 or not, since I find another form in a reference which I though it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is nearly correct. Here is a rather detailed derivation.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\right.}&\color{blue}{\left.a_ix^i\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^j\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\right)}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{i+j=m}\atop{i,j\geq 0}}a_ia_j\right)x^m\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\right)\\
> &=\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_ia_{m-i}\right)}_{=:b_m}x^m\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\right)\\
> &=\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}b_mx^m\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{m+k=n}\atop{m,k\geq 0}}b_ma_k\right)x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{n}b_ma_{n-m}\right)x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^ma_ia_{m-i}a_{n-m}\right)x^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{0\leq i\leq m\leq n}a_ia_{m-i}a_{n-m}\right)x^n}
> \end{align*}